# python imobiledevice module error

Tags: python

i write simple python script to test imobiledevice module ...
my script :

```
import imobiledevice

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dev = imobiledevice.iDevice()
```

but always get error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abbas/Main/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    import imobiledevice
  File "plist.pxd", line 8, in init imobiledevice (imobiledevice.c:57051)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plist.so: undefined symbol: plist_set_type
```

i compile last version of libimobiledevice from source ...

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely problem within the `imobiledevice`.

I would recommend to try compiling from some older (stable) version.

Comment: i install only  stable version of libimobiledevice or all requirement like usbmux or libusbmux ?

Comment: @user3585139 I am not sure I understood your last comment (the questionmark confuses me). I am not an expert on imobiledevice, just try to apply my general experience with python packages. Working with development versions of packages is fine (if you have reason for it), but if it fails, you either have to fix the bug, or return back to some older version. Sometime you I even turn few versions back if the latest one breaks things. Anyway, the simplest approach is to start with latest stable version of all packages and fiddle with versions and dev versions only if necessary.